# Pin Markers with D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm implementing a map that will markers by latitude and longitude. I'm using D3Js to create svg from a topojson file.

This is the implementation:

```
var places = [
        {
            name: "Longo, England",
            location: {
                latitude: 51.5,
                longitude: -0.116667
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Dublin, Irland",
            location: {
                latitude: 53.428590,
                longitude: -6.188024
            }
        }
    ]

    var margin = {top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10};
    var width = parseInt(d3.select('#map').style('width'));
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    var mapRatio = 1;
    var height = width * mapRatio;

    var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("data/uk.json", function(error, uk) {
        if (error) return console.error(error);

        var subunits = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits);

        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([0, 55.4])
            .rotate([4.4, 0])
            .scale(500)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(subunits)
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "subunit-boundary IRL");

        svg.selectAll(".subunit")
            .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
            .attr("d", path);

        svg.selectAll(".pin")
            .data(places)
            .enter()
            .append('image')
            .attr('class', 'datamaps-pin')
            .attr('xlink:href', 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/marker/pin-m+7e7e7e@2x.png')
            .attr('height', 40)
            .attr('width', 40)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + projection([
                        d.location.longitude,
                        d.location.latitude
                    ]) + ")"
            });
```

However the pins are out of position.

When I change the markers for simple points, it shall be in the right position

```
svg.selectAll(".pin")
            .data(places)
            .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + projection([
                        d.location.longitude,
                        d.location.latitude
                    ]) + ")"
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

A circle is drawn centred around the origin (x,y = 0) if you don't specify any x or y. An image however is drawn with its top left corner at the origin if you don't specify x or y.

To get the same effect as a circle add

```
.attr("x", -20)
.attr("y", -20)
```

to the image version of the pin.